# VB count files via ftp

Tags: vb.net, ftp

how to make VB count the number of items available in a folder of my website? i need to use FTP? i can make VB upload files, download files, or whatever,all using FTP, but i need him show me how many items i have in the specific folder.

I use this code for connect to FTP:

```
Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("adress"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list the files in the directory using the method `ListDirectoryDetails`:

```
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
```